# How to close this bottom bar in iOS9 simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios9

[image]

[image]

When I use iOS9 simulator, a bottom bar will be shown over my app. When keyboard appears, it can do some undo / paste actions. In the first picture, I even cannot see my UITabBar now. What is this bar and how can I close it?

Comment: In your attributes inspector, under view controller select `Hide bottom bar on push` and check if you still see this bar. Regards.

Comment: @PK20 This bar is not added by me. Looks like that it can do some undo / paste actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two options:

**1) Settings:**

```
Settings -> General -> Keyboard ->Shortcuts -> Switch to off
```

**2) Code (iOS 9 +):**

Objective-c:

```
textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```

Swift:

```
textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```